# TOAD for Oracle incorrectly returns week old data

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I work with TOAD for Oracle 10.6 to create a lot of queries, and for the first time I am having an issue where my SQLs are returning data from a week ago and not as of today, even though the table is only ever a snapshot of the current day. Even my SYSDATE field is returning the week old date. I have never had this happen before, and others in my group are not experiencing this. Is there a cache or other temporary data storage within TOAD which would need to be cleared out to solve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If `sysdate` is returning the wrong date, then I suspect that the system date is set incorrectly on the computer hosting Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was my first suspicion also, but my coworker was able to run the exact same SQL and both the data and sysdate returned correctly as of today.

Comment: Does `SQLPLUS.EXE` also return the incorrect date?

Comment: please post a [mcve]